# Socketio 1.0 get attributes from all clients

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, socket.io

I am currently working on a simple **socketio** application in which i am sending some parameters to envents and i am storing them into each socket.

```
socket.on('add user', function (data) {
    if (addedUser) return;

    // we store the username in the socket session for this client.
    socket.nickname = data.nickname;
    socket.userId = data.userId;
...
```

Then i am getting all socketio clients using var **io.engine.clients** and i am trying to obtain that parameters in other event like this:

```
socket.on('new message', function (data) {

 var clientsRoom = io.engine.clients;

 for(var c in clientsRoom){
    console.log(" Client: " + c.userId); //Error
    console.log(" Client: " + c); //outputs the socket ID
    console.log(" Client: " + c['userId']); //Error
  }
...
```

but i am unable to get my userID previously stored for all sockets. ¿What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `io.engine.clients`, you should use `io.sockets.sockets` (they aren't the same, `socket.io` adds an extra layer on top of `engine.io`). Also make sure that you treat it as an object, not an array:

```
var clientsRoom = io.sockets.sockets;

for (var id in clientsRoom) {
  var c = clientsRoom[id];
  console.log(" Client: " + c.userId);
  console.log(" Client: " + id);
}
```

Comment: If i put in my code one log after socket.userId = data.userId; printing socket.userId it prints me my user ID. But with your code, when trying to get it, is returning me: Client: undefined :-(

Comment: @walolinux I put the code I tested with in a Gist: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/080f62fc6d7a506d8f5a55bc3bf61252

Comment: Yep, is working, but i am realizing that i need to list all connected sockets in a room, not in general and then obtain userId...

Comment: @walolinux it looks like you can use `io.of('/').adapter.rooms[ROOMNAME]` for that.